# Error adding new TextBlock to Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I want to add text to my canvas in WPF. The code runs until I want to add the TextBlock to the canvas as a child, giving me this:

"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void txtbItemName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock txtItemName = new TextBlock();
            txtItemName.Text = txtbItemName.Text;
            txtItemName.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
            cnvImage.Children.Remove(txtItemName);
            cnvImage.Children.Add(txtbItemName); //The error screen showed up when running this line
        }
```

Comment: Typo. Check your spelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error. You are trying to remove the new item and add existing one.

Here is a right code for you:

```
 TextBlock txtItemName = new TextBlock();
 txtItemName.Text = txtbItemName.Text;
 txtItemName.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0);
 cnvImage.Children.Remove(txtbItemName);
 cnvImage.Children.Add(txtItemName);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your txtbItemName is already a child of an element in your XAML i suppose (can't see your XAML). because you have already created this element in your xaml it won't let you add it to the canvas.

Answer (score -2):

I found it: I indeed tried to place an object that was already present. I accidentally placed an existing textBOX (txtb) instead of a textBLOCK (txt). Thanks for the help though!